# Download data from CSI Syteline everyday

Tags: csi

I download 2 files from CSI Syteline everyday. Is there a way to automate it, so that without manual intervention the 2 view are downloaded to local

I manually download 2 views in excel everyday. Is there a way to automatically download the data views to my local folder everyday at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

If your download is from a Mongoose Report, it may be able to be scheduled as a background task, with email output.